# When i add a widget it overides the previous widget

Tags: python, kivy

Im working on a Chat Screen and ive successful put in a Scrollview and a box layout inside it but when the function to send message is called, it adds to the Scrollview but it overides what is already written in the scrollview. i want when i add a widget to the Scrollview it adds to the previous items on the scrollview rather than overriding it. Here is the code from my python file.

```
class Chat(Screen):



    def on_enter(self, *args):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        self.chatdestination = Label(
            text=firebase.get("/users/" + app.localId, 'first name') + " " + firebase.get('/users/' + app.localId,
                                                                                          'last name'),
            pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.95}, size_hint=[0.8, 0.1], color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
            font_name="fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf")

        self.add_widget(self.chatdestination)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chat, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.localId = None
        self.messagebutton = Button(text="Send", font_size = 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color= (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint= {"right": 1,"down": 1}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.messagebutton.bind(on_release = self.send_message)
        self.add_widget(self.messagebutton)


        self.messagetextinput = TextInput(width=Window.size[0]*0.8, hint_text= "Write a message", font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf", size_hint= [0.8, 0.1], pos_hint= {"left": 1,"down": 1})
        self.add_widget(self.messagetextinput)



        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 1)

    def on_key_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40:
            self.send_message(None)



    def send_message(self, _):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        message = self.messagetextinput.text
        if len(message) > 0:
            database.child("messages").child(app.localId).update({self.localId: message})
            self.chatbubble = Button(text=self.messagetextinput.text, background_color = [0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0], background_normal = "",
                                      pos_hint= {"center_x": 1}, color = (1, 1, 1, 1))
            self.chatbubble.size = self.chatbubble.texture_size

            self.ids.chatlayout.add_widget(self.chatbubble)
            self.ids.scrollview.scroll_to(self.chatbubble)
            self.messagetextinput.text = ""


            Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 0.1)


    def focus_text_input(self, _):
        self.messagetextinput.focus = True



class MyApp(App):
    refresh_token_file = "refresh_token.txt"
    placementtext = None
    id1 = None
    local1d = None
    placementid = None
    notification = None




    def build(self):
        self.refresh_token_file = self.user_data_dir + self.refresh_token_file
        self.thefirebase = MyFireBase()

        return sm
```

Here is my code from my kivy file

```
<Chat>

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    ScrollView:
        id: scrollview
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        size_hint: 1, 0.8

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 0, 0, 0, 0
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size



        BoxLayout:
            id: chatlayout
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 5
            padding: 10, 10
            size_hint_y: None
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it should work but I have an idea to try. At first add size_hint_y=None to your button:

```
self.chatbubble = Button(text=self.messagetextinput.text, background_color = [0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0], background_normal = "",
                                      pos_hint= {"center_x": 1}, color = (1, 1, 1, 1), size_hint_y=None)
```

And now BoxLayout is without any hints about sizes, so add this thing to set height of it's rows, usually it really helps:

```
        BoxLayout:
            id: chatlayout
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 5
            padding: 10, 10
            size_hint_y: None
            # add this
            height: self.minimum_height
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, that’s not the send message function, the send message function is “def send message” and I added it to the box layout. Kindly look the question again. Thanks

Comment: @Matthew1998 sorry, my mistake, I've changed the answer, try it.

Comment: When I add widgets in the kivy file in works as intended, even when the widgets have the same pos_hint

Comment: @Matthew1998 is it possible that you create new object of Chat screen every time you push the button and you add the only last widget there?

Comment: i dont think so, but incase how do i stop that from happening